# vim variable has unwanted trailing char

Tags: vim, grep

In my vimrc I try to store the output of grep into a vim variable

```
let w:tex_file =  system("grep -lZ '\\documentclass' *.tex")
```

On my linux box this works perfectly.

```
let w:tex_file main.tex
```

But on my macbook I have an unwanted trailing character '^A'

```
let w:tex_file main.tex^A
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: are the two grep same (version, implementation) on your linux and mac boxes?

Comment: They are different (2.14 on linux and 2.5.1 on osx), but the output of the grep statement is the same on both boxes when I try them in the terminal. Both times there is no trailing character in the output.

Comment: Does this only happen with `grep`, or also with any `system()` call, e.g. `system('echo main.tex')`?!

Comment: With `echo`, I get a `^@` as trailing char on both systems. I made a mistake above. The trailing char in osx is `^A` not just a `^`. (I updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing character `^@` that you see is the new-line character. You can get rid (and you should) easy like this :

```
let w:tex_file =  system("grep -lZ '\\documentclass' *.tex")[:-2]
```

OR

```
let w:tex_file =  system("grep -lZ '\\documentclass' *.tex")
let w:tex_file = w:tex_file[:-2]
```

Comment: This actually helped thanks. I think that the `-Z` is different handled in both systems. I removed this attribute whereby both system have a trailing `^@` at the end which I now remove with your solution. Thanks